# Redirect to previous URL after admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, redirect, admin-login

I want **admin** users to be redirected to the url they opened after login.
They should get links to a custom module page in the **admin** area, like

> https://magento.example/index.php/admin/admin_mycoolmodule/adminhtml_viewawesome/view/showpage/awesome/howmuch/9001/

Obviously, they will be redirected to the login page, unless they are already logged in.

How can I redirect them back to this page after login?

Secret keys in the URL are disabled and can stay that way.

Now they get the configured default page (default was Dashboard) instead.

Comment: ok, basially you want to redirect admin to redirect to your custom page instead of dashboard, after login, right ?

Comment: Nope, that would just be a setting. I want it to redirect to whatever URL was open before login.

Comment: I don't think you can do this out of the box. You will need to make a customization

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour in Magento? If you try to go to an admin page you get redirected to the login page and after a successful login you go back to that page not the dashboard.

Comment: In Magento 1.8+ on a default installation it isn't. I also couldn't find a setting to change it.

Comment: It is the default behaviour for the frontend. For the backend it takes you to the Dashboard. Maybe you could replicate it. The whole implementation is done in code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php. Look for the getBeforeAuthUrl and setBeforeAuthUrl. Anyway, it isn't 5 minute job.

Answer (score 1):

As all the comments stated before, its not out of the box.
Here are some hints on where/what you may need to adjust:

```
Mage_Admin_Model_User

public function getStartupPageUrl()
    {
        $startupPage = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_STARTUP_PAGE);
        $aclResource = 'admin/' . $startupPage;
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($aclResource)) {
            $nodePath = 'menu/' . join('/children/', explode('/', $startupPage)) . '/action';
            $url = (string)Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')->getAdminhtmlConfig()->getNode($nodePath);
            if ($url) {
                return $url;
            }
        }
        return $this->findFirstAvailableMenu();
    }
```

I have never tried it but this seems to be the method called from

```
Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController
```

and there is the IndexAction that calls the above function.
Since this is the admin, doing a rewrite of the Model will probably be easier.

```
/**
 * Admin area entry point
 * Always redirects to the startup page url
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $url = $session->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl();
    if ($session->isFirstPageAfterLogin()) {
        // retain the "first page after login" value in session (before redirect)
        $session->setIsFirstPageAfterLogin(true);
    }
    $this->_redirect($url);
}
```

So, modifying getStartupPageUrl() to have your URL seems very likely the best place to try this.

This is all theoretical, I have not tried it yet, but if you need a sample module, I can certainly run through this and provide it.

If every admin user will end up on the same page, its pretty easy to do, if there is some dynamic elements, it will be a bit harder to facilitate.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9+ there is Mage_Admin_Model_Redirectpolicy. In here is `getRedirectUrl`:

```
 public function getRedirectUrl(Mage_Admin_Model_User $user, Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request = null, $alternativeUrl = null)
{
    if (empty($request)) {
        return;
    }
    $countRequiredParams = ($this->_urlModel->useSecretKey()
        && $request->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME)) ? 1 : 0;
    $countGetParams = count($request->getUserParams()) + count($request->getQuery());

    return ($countGetParams > $countRequiredParams) ?
        $this->_urlModel->getUrl($user->getStartupPageUrl()) : $alternativeUrl;
}
}
```

As described in the function comment: "Redirect to startup page after logging in if request contains any params (except security key)"

Changing that return statement to always return the `$alternativeUrl`, solves the problem. Having said this, I'm not sure what other problems it causes (specifically in regard to security). Would need to dig deeper.